# How to draw polygons in golang without anti-aliasing?

Tags: go, graphics, 2d

I'd like to draw and fill polygons in golang without any anti-aliasing.
Popular packages like https://github.com/fogleman/gg don't let the anti-aliasing to be turned off in their rendering.
Any idea on how to accomplish that?

Comment: Not in the standard lib. Are you asking for 3rd party libs? That's off-topic.

Comment: If rendering solid in solid colors, you could scan the anti-aliased image for all pixels that are not the background color and not the polygon color, and then set them to one of those values (probably based on a threshold medium value) to recreate jaggies

Comment: That's an idea Disco, the problem is I'm not actually using real colors, but I'm encoding some value into the r g b a. So I need those values not to be altered by the anti-aliasing.